# What happens if I delete a nonexistent key in Python Dictionary Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say buff is a dictionary. I do `del buff[k]`, but k is not a key in the buff. Is this an error, or you python just passes the line like nothing happened?

Comment: `buff[k]` triggers a key error, `del` isn't even called.

Comment: The good thing about Python is you can always put those two lines of code in a file and test it yourself. Or even better/faster, throw it into [IPython](https://ipython.org/). Asking on SO however takes time and nowadays you risk a lot of downvotes for questions not reusable to others. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let's test this:

```
>>> buff={1:2,4:5}
>>> del buff[1]
>>> del buff[6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 6
```

but in this case, `del` has nothing to do with it. Accessing a non-existing key of a dictionary with `[]` notation raises `KeyError`

Note that it's nicer to use `buff.pop(k)` (in that case the *delete operation* triggers a `KeyError` if doesn't exist, same outcome)

To create a non-crashing/fail-safe method just do:

```
if k in buff:
    buff.pop(k)
```

or (better ask for forgiveness than permission):

```
try:
   buff.pop(k)
except KeyError:
   pass
```

Comment: However, if k really exists, I want to delete it. Does pop() delete the key inside the buffer?